# Can't understand how to code Func<Func<T1, T2>, T3>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-extensions

I have this method:

```
public static IQueryable<char> Test(this string text, Func<Func<char, bool>, int> func)
```

Here char is the character to find in text, bool determines whether the character is found and int returns the index of the character in the text.

How should I write this code? Thanks.

Comment: `func` is a function, that accepts a function and returns an `int`. That input function accepts a `char` and returns a `bool`

Comment: Thanks. I understand this. But I don't understand how to properly code this. I need an example.

Comment: Since there is not a character source in your function, it's hard to detect an index of char. It seems the type of `func` must be `Func<IQueryable<char>, Func<char, bool>, int>` or `Func<IEnumerable<char>, Func<char, bool>, int>`.

Comment: I understood that I needed more methods than I wanted to have. I tried to put a lot in one extension method and there should be a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that will make you understand what this does.
I have no idea why you would need this but there probably is a reason :).

```
    // These Func's take a char and return a boolean value.
    Func<char, bool> f1 = (ch) => ch == 'a';
    Func<char, bool> f2 = (ch) => ch == 'b';

    char chr = 'a';

    // This Func takes a function (of the type we saw above) and returns an integer.
    Func<Func<char, bool>, int> func = (foo) => foo(chr) ? 1 : 0;

    // Run the complex Func by passing a function as an input param and receiving an integer as a response.
    int res1 = func(f1); // 1
    int res2 = func(f2); // 0
```

By your request, here is another example (I still can't find a good usage but whatever):

```
    string text = "TesTinG";
    Func<char, bool> IsCapital = ch => ch == char.ToUpper(ch);
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (char chr in text.ToCharArray())
    {
        Func<Func<char, bool>, int> func = fn => fn(chr) ? 1 : 0;
        counter += func(IsCapital);
    }
```

Comment: Hello. Very thanks for this code and explanation. Could you give a more elaborate example how to use this code?

Comment: @DeividasGrigas - I've added another example of counting capital letters in a string. I still can't find a good use with the Func<Func<char,bool>,int> but whatever..

Comment: Could you help me some more,,, I have this code:              Func<bool, StringParameters, StringParameters> f1 = (found, p) => new StringParameters(p.Character, p.Text.IndexOf(p.Character, p.Position) != -1);
    
             Action<bool> comparisonType = (found, p) => f1(found, p).Position != -1 ? true : false;//new StringParameters(p., d)).Position;
 
             Func<Func<char, int, StringParameters>, StringParameters> f2 = (c, index) => text.IndexOf(c, comparisonType); What is wrong with it?

Comment: @DeividasGrigas - You need to add more code. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'll open another question then. I'll write the linq in the next comment. Thank you for your help. Where did you learn linq extensions? What material did you read or watch? Thanks.

Comment: I understood the code already by writing the post so there will be no link.